# C++ objects contiguous in memory?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory

I am not very good at C++ and I currently porting some piece of code to C. It allocates a big array of objects like this:

```
o_list::Node** nodes = (o_list::Node**)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(o_list::Node*));
```

and then fills each position with:

```
for(int u=0;u<SIZE;u++)
   nodes[u] = new o_list::Node();
```

From what I understand, the only assurance we have regarding contigous memory is that the **pointers** to the objects are in fact contiguous, i.e. it might happen that we have:

```
 _____________________
|x||x||x||x||x||x||x|x| -> contiguous array of pointers;
 |   \ \         
 |    \ \______
 |     \       \
 O      O       O       -> not contiguous positions of objects;
```

To correct this, I tried to malloc the first array (of pointers) and then malloc an array of objects, and then assign the pointers to the right positions, like this:

```
o_list::Node** nodes = (o_list::Node**)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(o_list::Node*));

o_list::Node* contObjs = (o_list::Node*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(o_list::Node));

for(int u=0;u<SIZE;u++){
   contObjs[u] = o_list::Node();
   nodes[u] = &contObjs[u];
}
```

But this leads to a segmentation fault. I would like to know if my assumption is correct and why I have a segmentation fault in the second option.

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `SIZE`? And what does `o_list::Node()` do? If this is a class constructor, why don't you just use `new` instead?

Comment: You don't seem to need an array of pointers here. Why not simply allocate an array of objects?

Comment: Never ever use malloc in C++ code.

Comment: If you have an array of objects it is sufficient to have the pointer to the first object and run with the index over all objects. The pointer indirection is useless. Why you go back to C?

Comment: @barakmanos I am sorry I am not showing you more code, but I do need pointers in the rest of the code.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I am trying to port this to C...

Comment: @BaummitAugen: In this case it's warranted. The question is literally about converting C++ to C.

Comment: Malloc is C, new is C++ (essentially malloc and call constructor, but for POD types you could use malloc). You could preallocate array and then use placement new to construct your objects to get them in a cache-friendly, contiguous layout. But then you do not have pure C.

Comment: Does `Node` have a `operator =` defined?

Comment: I find this question a bit unclear. Is it about porting from C++ to C or is it about allocating a contiguous area of memory?

Comment: What does the assignment operator do? In particular, does it make any assumptions about the previous state of the object (which is unspecified after `malloc`). Can you provide enough of a [test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), without unrelated errors, that we don't have to guess what your real code is doing?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Seems unlikely since `op=` is simple in C

Comment: @Henrik: `operator=`? In C?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: But this isn't yet C (as evidenced by the `::`). There may be some vestigial code doing something we can't see.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit all the code examples are `C++`.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Both at the same time.

Comment: Recommend VTC as "needs a testcase"

Comment: I don't know why there's a close vote for off topic.  It seems to me to be pretty much a programming question.

Comment: How is it relevant that objects are contiguous if they are referenced via an array of pointers? Or worded differently, _if_ objects are allocated contiguously, why would one want another array of pointers? It seems like one makes the other superfluous (you can use something like `allobjects[some_index]`perfectly fine).

Comment: @JeremyP: "Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it". There's not enough information here to guess what might be wrong with the missing code. The only answerable part of the question ("are arrays contiguous?") is rather trivial.

Comment: @MikeSeymour It might be trivial to you, but that doesn't necessarily make it trivial to the question asker.  And if there is not enough information there's a different category for closing than off topic - or, instead of being snotty about it, you could ask in the comments for further info.

Comment: @JeremyP: I meant trivial compared to the bulk of this question (as well as trivially googlable) - answering just that part, and ignoring the main question, wouldn't be very helpful to anybody. I and others did ask for further info, but it wasn't forthcoming; so I voted to close for the reason I quoted above, which describes the situation exactly. Sorry if you find that snotty, but removing unanswerable questions is how this site maintains its quality.

Comment: @a3mlord : I really apologize for before. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right lines, though getting rid of that first array entirely would be better (if you can). It may involve some design changes elsewhere in your program, so let's leave that for now.

As for your segmentation fault, the only problem I can see is if `SIZE` is not equal to `300000`, you will go out of bounds. Why not use `SIZE` in the loop?

Comment: Nice catch, but SIZE is indeed = 300000. Sorry. +1 for the catch. Edited.

Comment: @a3mlord: Then I'm going to ask you to present a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because this is therefore entirely unanswerable. I would also suggest abstracting away the code-porting business as it doesn't seem particularly relevant to your segfault.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why you need an array of pointers to begin with.

Nevertheless, here are several ways to achieve what you're asking:

---

```
o_list::Node  objArray[SIZE];
o_list::Node* ptrArray[SIZE];

for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    ptrArray[i] = objArray+i;
```

---

```
o_list::Node* objArray = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(o_list::Node));
o_list::Node* ptrArray[SIZE];

for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    ptrArray[i] = objArray+i;
```

---

```
o_list::Node   objArray[SIZE];
o_list::Node** ptrArray = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(o_list::Node*));

for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    ptrArray[i] = objArray+i;
```

---

```
o_list::Node*  objArray = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(o_list::Node));
o_list::Node** ptrArray = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(o_list::Node*));

for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    ptrArray[i] = objArray+i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on C++ but isn't there an array form of `new` that will allocate a contiguous array of objects?  Something like this?

```
MyClass * arrayOfMyClass = new MyClass[5];
```

Now you may say "but I'm converting it to C, and C doesn't have new".  This is true, but C also doesn't have classes and operator overloading and copy constructors.  If you want to use malloc, you need to grasp the nettle and convert your Node class into a C struct.  The reason for this is that `malloc()` is not the C equivalent to `new`.

`new` allocated memory *and* constructs the objects.  `malloc` only allocates memory.  You can't even guarantee that the memory it gives you is zero filled.  In C you need to provide an initialisation function to do what the constructor would do.  The C equivalent of your code would go something like:

```
void Node_init(struct Node* aNode)
{
    // Any initialisation you need to do of its members
}

...

struct Node* contObjs = malloc(SIZE * sizeof *contObjs); // or use calloc to get zero filled memory

for(int u=0;u<SIZE;u++) {
   Node_init(&contObjs[u]); // Pass the address of the u'th element
}
```